# Floating menu in html and css

Tags: html, css, image, floating, squarespace

I have a question about a floating picture I want to put on my page.
I tried everything but it will not work how I want it.
The problem is that de picture float perfectly, but when I open the page on a diffrent computer the picture is in the middle of the content.
I tried postion;fixed but that wil not work.
Maybe I put the wrong codes in HTML and CSS i´m using squarespace.

Can somebody help me out ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your html and css.

Comment: post your code here :- jsfiddle.net

Comment: and btw, please give us the browser you used on your computer as well as the browser on the other computer (and same for the screen resolutions)

Comment: I put the codes in her http://jsfiddle.net/Pimster/F4kCb/

Comment: I use Chrome on both computers, the are different screens with different resolutions but the picture have to stay just near the content on both screens

Comment: That code you've posted isn't very helpful I'm afraid. The CSS doesn't refer to the HTML and we can't really help without seeing more html/css.

Comment: what kind of code I have to put in ? , for the same result

Comment: Why don't you share the specific page you are having issues with on squarespace (if it's public)?

Comment: well, the `moduleContent19120970` in your css is referring to ... nothing. Same for the Html span which has the classes `full-image-block ssNonEditable`... and nothing in the css

Comment: I'm sorry I am not very good in this. Sow leMoisela what I have to put in then ?

Comment: I now put the code like this jsfiddle.net/Pimster/HvqYV/ but stil the picture will move when I look on another computer, at 1 computer the picture work perfectly but another computer the picture move to diffrent location ??? Who help me ??

Answer (score 1):

By `position:fixed` you place your image relative to window borders. Of course, unless your site is absolutely stretchable, it will produce different results when viewed on different resolutions. Sometimes obscuring content.

You need something that will float your image within designated area. For example, the following javascript code will do: http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating/confined_demo.html